# How to get the result of a jQuery AJAX call then call another function

Tags: ajax, jquery, call

Basically I am trying to call a function (function 1), that get the results from another function (function 2). And this function 2 is making an ajax call.

So the code would be like this:

```
function f1 () {
    var results = f2();
}

function f2() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/test.php',
        success: function(msg){
        }
    });
}
```

I know that is I display an alert in the success function, I get the results. But how can we make this result be sended back?

I tryed to do something like this inside function 2 without success:

return msg;

thanks for your help

Comment: You commented in meder's post about trying to have multiple calls using the same ajax. Can you expand on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In theory, this is possible using jQuery's `async: false` setting. That setting makes the call synchronous, i.e. the browser waits until it's done.

This is considered bad practice, though, because it can freeze the browser. You should re-structure your script so you can do the relevant things in the `success` callback instead of `f1`. I know this is less convenient than what you do in `f1()`, but it's the right way to deal with Ajax's asynchronous nature.

Answer (score 2):

You can forcefully make the request synchronous ( kinda losing the benefit of ajax ) but making your code work:

```
function f2() {
    var ret = false;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/test.php',
        async:false,
        success: function(msg){
           ret = msg
        }
    });
    return ret;
}
```

Otherwise, you have to add a callback in your `success` function if you want to keep it asynchronous..

```
function f2() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/test.php',
        async:false,
        success: function(msg){
           doSomething(msg);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answers guys

As I understand it's an asynchronous/synch issue...

My purpuse was to avoid having the same AJAX call several times, when I have several different things to do on the call result.

So the way I was looking for is having the AJAX function called by one, 2 or more different functions... 

But as I understand if I need to keep the asynchronous mode I need to do it a different way.